# Nmap greping and awking the results

Tags: linux, recursion, awk, dns, nmap

i have nmap and am able to do dns-recursion checks on a local pc. the output is

nmap -sU -p 53 --script=dns-recursion 198.162.3.5

PORT   STATE  SERVICE REASON

53/udp  open  domain  udp-response
|_dns-recursion: Recursion appears to be enabled

Now my question is if i were to do a scan on all my computers how can i grep and awk in real time ( i donot want to awk and grep the output file) such that only the ip of servers that do recursion are printed. I have the following  command in mind, but itsnot working

nmap -sU -p 53 --script=dns-recursion  | grep "enabled" | awk '{ print $13 }'

Answer (score 0):

Please try with -oG flag, it gives grepable output

```
nmap -oG -sU -p 53 --script=dns-recursion | grep "enabled" | awk '{ print $13 }'
```

I hope this will solve the purpose.If you are not working on an old system on which nmap -oG flag is not deprecated as it stands deprecated now.

So, if `-oG` doesn't work you can try with `-oX` for XML output and then grep.

Comment: does the $13 means the 13th word from the left from the nmap output ?

Comment: yep that's the intention